# Using native java script in gradle build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have read on [unity plugin creation documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJARPlugins.html) that we can use .java files and use native functions without creating plugins , but wheni put .java file in unity3d project i cannot call its methods using JNIUnity calls , and also unable to mark the file as plugin as described in documentation

Is there a particular way to make it work?

Comment: what version of unity are you using?

Comment: I am using unity5.6, is there specific version of unity which supports this feature?

Comment: yes but i'm not sure which. the documentation you linked is for 2018.2, maybe it's not in 5.6

Comment: yeah, it says at the bottom of the docs "Support for Java source file plug-ins added for Android player in 2018.2"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out , that`s very dumb of me :) didn`t saw that